# Trying to individually target multiple Switch components with vanilla addEventListner but only hitting the first one - I'm not using 'this' correctly

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have multiple Switch components of `input type="checkbox"` on a page and I want to toggle a class `.active` on these *individually* via `addEventListner()`. I'm using vanilla, not jQuery.

I have it working on the *first* element but none of the others work. I need them all to work independently.

Obviously I'm not targeting 'this' correctly. I've made seperate stabs at it using combinations of function declaration, expression, standard function syntax and arrow. With arrow I was aiming at using the lexical scope to affect a correct 'this' scope.

Here's a **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/artcrowned/pen/BaNZNBr)** with 3 attempts; open console to view the `.active` class toggle on the *first* Switch element.

Here's one example (also in the pen):

```
// Working on ONE checkbox:
let fireMySwitch = function(inputType, className) {
  let mySwitchInput = document.querySelector(`input[type=${inputType}`);

  mySwitchInput.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    !this.checked ? this.classList.remove(className) : this.classList.add(className);
  }, false);
}
fireMySwitch('checkbox', 'active');
```

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="cell my-switch__block">
  <p class="my-switch__copy">Switch</p>
  <div class="switch large">
    <input class="switch-input" id="yes-no_2" type="checkbox" name="mySwitch_2">
    <label class="switch-paddle" for="yes-no_2">
      <span class="show-for-sr">Switch</span>
      <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">Yes</span>
      <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">No</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone advise how I can correctly target each element independently to toggle the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple inputs, so you need to iterate over all of them that match the selector, not just one:

```js
let fireMySwitch = function(inputType, className) {
  for (const mySwitchInput of document.querySelectorAll(`input[type=${inputType}`)) {
    mySwitchInput.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      !this.checked ? this.classList.remove(className) : this.classList.add(className);
    });
  }
}
fireMySwitch('checkbox', 'active');
```

```css
.active + * {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="grid-x grid-padding-x small-up-2 align-center-middle align-stretch my-switch__outer">
  <div class="cell my-switch__block">
    <p class="my-switch__copy">Switch</p>
    <div class="switch large">
      <input class="switch-input" id="yes-no_1" type="checkbox" name="mySwitch_1">
      <label class="switch-paddle" for="yes-no_1">
        <span class="show-for-sr">Switch</span>
        <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">Yes</span>
        <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">No</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell my-switch__block">
    <p class="my-switch__copy">Switch</p>
    <div class="switch large">
      <input class="switch-input" id="yes-no_2" type="checkbox" name="mySwitch_2">
      <label class="switch-paddle" for="yes-no_2">
        <span class="show-for-sr">Switch</span>
        <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">Yes</span>
        <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">No</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell my-switch__block">
    <p class="my-switch__copy">Switch</p>
    <div class="switch large">
      <input class="switch-input" id="yes-no_3" type="checkbox" name="mySwitch_3">
      <label class="switch-paddle" for="yes-no_3">
        <span class="show-for-sr">Switch</span>
        <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">Yes</span>
        <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">No</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell my-switch__block">
    <p class="my-switch__copy">Switch</p>
    <div class="switch large">
      <input class="switch-input" id="yes-no_4" type="checkbox" name="mySwitch_4">
      <label class="switch-paddle" for="yes-no_4">
        <span class="show-for-sr">Switch</span>
        <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">Yes</span>
        <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">No</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also consider using `classList.toggle` instead:

```js
let fireMySwitch = function(inputType, className) {
  for (const mySwitchInput of document.querySelectorAll(`input[type=${inputType}`)) {
    mySwitchInput.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      this.classList.toggle(className);
    });
  }
}
fireMySwitch('checkbox', 'active');
```

```css
.active + * {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="grid-x grid-padding-x small-up-2 align-center-middle align-stretch my-switch__outer">
  <div class="cell my-switch__block">
    <p class="my-switch__copy">Switch</p>
    <div class="switch large">
      <input class="switch-input" id="yes-no_1" type="checkbox" name="mySwitch_1">
      <label class="switch-paddle" for="yes-no_1">
        <span class="show-for-sr">Switch</span>
        <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">Yes</span>
        <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">No</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell my-switch__block">
    <p class="my-switch__copy">Switch</p>
    <div class="switch large">
      <input class="switch-input" id="yes-no_2" type="checkbox" name="mySwitch_2">
      <label class="switch-paddle" for="yes-no_2">
        <span class="show-for-sr">Switch</span>
        <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">Yes</span>
        <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">No</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell my-switch__block">
    <p class="my-switch__copy">Switch</p>
    <div class="switch large">
      <input class="switch-input" id="yes-no_3" type="checkbox" name="mySwitch_3">
      <label class="switch-paddle" for="yes-no_3">
        <span class="show-for-sr">Switch</span>
        <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">Yes</span>
        <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">No</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell my-switch__block">
    <p class="my-switch__copy">Switch</p>
    <div class="switch large">
      <input class="switch-input" id="yes-no_4" type="checkbox" name="mySwitch_4">
      <label class="switch-paddle" for="yes-no_4">
        <span class="show-for-sr">Switch</span>
        <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">Yes</span>
        <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">No</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Forgot to say that I had tinkered with .querySelectorAll but obv not in the right context with a for loop. Will mark this as accepted.

Comment: Actually haven't really used 'for  of' loops lile this before now so can see how obviously useful they are. Cheers

Comment: Yep, though any iteration method would work - `for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length...` or `querySelectorAll(...).forEach((input) => { ...`

Comment: Yes, I was asking too much of querySelector/querySelectorAll - thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the forEach method to loop over all inputs and achieve the same effect.

```js
let fireMySwitch = function(inputType, className) {
  const mySwitchInputs = document.querySelectorAll(`input[type=${inputType}`);   
  mySwitchInputs.forEach(mySwitchInput => {
      mySwitchInput.addEventListener("change", e => {
         e.target.classList.toggle(className)
   }) 
})      
}
fireMySwitch('checkbox', 'active');
```

```css
.active + * {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="grid-x grid-padding-x small-up-2 align-center-middle align-stretch my-switch__outer">
  <div class="cell my-switch__block">
    <p class="my-switch__copy">Switch</p>
    <div class="switch large">
      <input class="switch-input" id="yes-no_1" type="checkbox" name="mySwitch_1">
      <label class="switch-paddle" for="yes-no_1">
        <span class="show-for-sr">Switch</span>
        <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">Yes</span>
        <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">No</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell my-switch__block">
    <p class="my-switch__copy">Switch</p>
    <div class="switch large">
      <input class="switch-input" id="yes-no_2" type="checkbox" name="mySwitch_2">
      <label class="switch-paddle" for="yes-no_2">
        <span class="show-for-sr">Switch</span>
        <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">Yes</span>
        <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">No</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell my-switch__block">
    <p class="my-switch__copy">Switch</p>
    <div class="switch large">
      <input class="switch-input" id="yes-no_3" type="checkbox" name="mySwitch_3">
      <label class="switch-paddle" for="yes-no_3">
        <span class="show-for-sr">Switch</span>
        <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">Yes</span>
        <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">No</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell my-switch__block">
    <p class="my-switch__copy">Switch</p>
    <div class="switch large">
      <input class="switch-input" id="yes-no_4" type="checkbox" name="mySwitch_4">
      <label class="switch-paddle" for="yes-no_4">
        <span class="show-for-sr">Switch</span>
        <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">Yes</span>
        <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">No</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, and cheers for the hit. I've used forEach before and in hindsight it's so clear what I wasn't doing, namely looping through each element instead of just targetting them via querySelector().